# How to find consonants in an array and append ut after them in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, function

I am working on a project and in need of some assistance. I am told in the assignment the following:

> The Language of Tut
>
> The tut language is a simple encoded language
>   where words are spelled out and the letters "ut" are placed after
>   every consonant, vowels are left as they are. So the word "Hello", in
>   tut become "Hutelutluto" The word "Goodbye" becomes "Gutoodutbutyute".
>   The sentence "How are you today?", becomes "Hutowut arute yutou
>   tutodutayut?".
>
> The Programs
>
> For this lab you will need to write two (2) C programs.
>   The first should be be able to accept an English sentence from the
>   user and convert it into Tut and the second program should accept a
>   Tut sentence from the user and convert it to English. Both the
>   original and converted sentences should be displayed for the user in
>   both programs.
>
> Functions and Header Files
>
> Find at least one reason to create a
>   function that can be used in both of the two programs. The function
>   should have high functional integrity and be loosely coupled. The
>   function should be kept in a header file that will be included into
>   each of the two programs.
>
> You should submit two C source code files and 1 header file for this
>   assignment. Everything that's needed for the programs to compile must
>   be included.

I am not concerned with the function right now. Just trying to accomplish the main task with the arrays.

Here is what I have so far.

```
/*
EnglishToTut
*/


#include <stdio.h>

int input_check (char [], char [], int);

int main ( void ) {

  const max_str_len = 50;
  int c, i;
  char eng_str[max_str_len];
  char vowel[] = {'a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U'};
  char consonant[] = {'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'y', 'z', '\0'};

  printf("Welcome to the program Tut.\n");
  printf("Please enter a string to convert to Tut: ");
  scanf(" %s", eng_str);

  for ( c = 0; c < max_str_len; c++) {
    if (eng_str[c] == consonant[c]) {
      printf("%sut", eng_str);
    }
  }

// while ( input_check(consonant, eng_str, max_str_len) != 1 ) { //write a   loop with an if statement that uses function to check for consanants and then append ut.
  //   if( input_check(consonant, eng_str, max_str_len) == 1 ) {
  //     printf("%s\n", eng_str);
  //   } else if ( input_check(consonant, eng_str, max_str_len) == 0 ) {
  //     printf("%s\n", eng_str);
  //   }
  // }
```

Please ignore the commented code. 
But my question is why is the program only appending ut to the first char of the string and not to each of the consonants?

Comment: If you walk through this in a debugger, you will surely spot your mistake. It's easier to see things happening one line at a time than it is all at once.  For bonus points, make your program compile without warnings. If you're not willing ti do that before trying to solve runtime problems, you're only wasting time.

Comment: _The function should be kept in a header file that will be included into each of the two programs._ - If your professor means the function implementation, rather than just the prototype (and based on the later instructions, that is what he means), should be in this header... tell your professor to not encourage such garbage programming practice.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I will walk through it and get and see what i can find out. I'm not exactly sure what you mean about the function comment though. He has us create a whole function and then put in a header file for both programs to use. I just have it written in the program with the prototype for testing right now.

Comment: About the function, what I mean is: placing source code inside a header file is (with very few exceptions) garbage and if you told a prospective employer that you routinely did that, it could easily cause you to not get offered a job. By requiring that practice of you, your professor is suggesting that it's routinely acceptable - and that's a disservice to you and every one of his students.

Comment: Ah I see. I will keep that in mind. Thank you. So to get this straight I should only ever put a prototype in the header file? I'm sorry if I'm completely off base still I'm just trying to make sure I am understanding correctly.

Comment: There are other things which should exist in header files but normally, code you expect to compile should not be (except where required by your instructor as in this assignment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are looping through the index to the first and second array with the same index. Although you are looping through the list of characters and appending "ut" to the character under a certain conditional statement, you are only preforming this function if the character at the index to both arrays is the same. Add a secondary loop around the if statement and use this loop to index the array of consonants.
To make your program more concise, it may be easier to get rid of the array of consonants and just check if the character is not a vowel. Try this...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int inArr(char character, char *letters, int size) {//retuns the number of times a character appears in an array
    int counter=0;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        if(character==letters[i]) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

int main () {

    int maxLen = 50;
    char eng_str[maxLen];
    char vowels[] = {'a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U', ' ', 0};//array of characters withought "ut" appended

    printf("Welcome to the program Tut.\n");
    printf("Please enter a string to convert to Tut: ");

    int i=0;//gets string and saves to eng_str
    while((eng_str[i] = getchar())!='\n') {
            i++ ;
        if(i>=maxLen) {
            printf("\nSTRING TOO LONG\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    int a=0;//stores the length of the typed message as a
    while(eng_str[a] != '\n') {
        a++;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<a; i++) {//loop through entered string
        if(inArr(eng_str[i], vowels, (sizeof(vowels)/sizeof(vowels[0])))==0) {//if character at index i is not in vowels append ut
            printf("%cut", eng_str[i]);
        }else {//else print just the character
            printf("%c", eng_str[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

I used `getchar()` instead of `scanf()` because it was difficult to change the length of the array based on the input with `scanf()` and with `getchar()` you can just tell it it to search for the `'/n'` character. `scanf()` also truncated the string to the first space in the string.

You could also attempt to dynamically allocate the characters to a character array but if you declare `char *eng_str` and then try to pass characters to it the program throws a segmentation fault.

Comment: hopefully you can post the code which is can help us to know your method

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that every loop you check if the current element in the string is an alphabet and if it is true you pass the current letter of the inputted string to a function that would check if that letter is a consonant or not.

Checks whether the element given is a vowel or not

```
int isCons(char a)
{
   int retVal,up;

   up = toupper(a);

   if(up == 65 || up == 69 || up == 73 || up == 79 || up == 85){ //Check the Ascii value of the character if it is a vowel
       retVal = 0;
   }else{
       retVal = 1;
   }

   return retVal;
   }
```

Prints the given String

```
void Convert(char a[])
{   
   int x,len;

   for(x = 0,len = strlen(a); x < len; x++ ){
       printf("%c",a[x]);
       if(isalpha(a[x])){
           if(isCons(a[x]) == 1){
               printf("ut");
           }
       }
   }
 }
```